# spring mvc and ajax form submition

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

How ajax determine if the transaction is made success or error?

I have a ajax function to handle the form submission:

```
function createTranCall() {
    var nameval = $('#c-t-t').val(); 
    var amountval = $('#c-t-a').val();
    alert(nameval + " " + amountval);
    //return false;
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/create/transaction",
        cache: false,
        data: "traname=" + nameval + "&tranamount=" + amountval,
        success: function(response) {
            /* $('#result').html('');
            var obj = JSON.parse(reponse);
            $('#result').html(obj.name); */
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error while request ..");
        }
    });
}
```

and my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/transaction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public MyTransaction createTran(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("create new Transaction");
        MyTransaction myTran = MyTransaction.getInstance();

        String name = request.getParameter("traname");
        String amount = request.getParameter("tranamount");
        System.out.println("name: " + name + " - amount: " + amount);

        myTran.setName(name);
        return myTran;
    }
```

So I can send and get the data from my controller. However I keep hitting error state, and have no clue how I get there. I have search something like "What make ajax hit error state" but couldn't find anything useful (Probably I didn't come up with better keyword).

Any help and suggestion would be a big help. Thank you.

Comment: Look in your browser's network tab: the response's code was most likely 500: Internal Server Error. This means you'll need to look at your application's server-side log output to find the exception's stack trace that shows what caused the failure.

Comment: Thank for the hint. I got "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported". I try to omit method=RequestMethod.POST, but it doesnt help.

Comment: Looks like the Dispatcher Servlet matches the wrong method - do you have any other methods with the same URL mapping? Are you sure you're showing the actual code you're running? It could be quicker to experiment and send requests using a REST client  (e.g. Advanced REST Client for Chrome) rather than your own client application.

Answer (score 0):

First try to send only string from the server

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/transaction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public MyTransaction createTran(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("create new Transaction");
        MyTransaction myTran = MyTransaction.getInstance();

        String name = request.getParameter("traname");
        String amount = request.getParameter("tranamount");
        System.out.println("name: " + name + " - amount: " + amount);

        myTran.setName(name);
        return myTran;
    }
```

convert it to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/transaction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createTran(){

        return "works";
    }
```

if this does not works then it means it has problem with server java code. this also mean there is no problem with your ajax call

Second you can change `MyTransaction` return type to string to see if it works. do change the type while returning the value.

Answer (score -1):

as I understand, you always get this block:

```
error: function() {
            alert("Error while request ..");
        }
```

the most common issue is that there is no mapper your class `MyTransaction` to `JSON`, etc.
try to add:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar
- com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.jar
  or if you are using **maven**:

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

  the version can be different

  also you can explicitly tell `AJAX` the type of data that you're expecting back from the server:

  ```
  dataType: 'json'
  ```

  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/


  if you still get error state, try to do something like

  ```
      $.ajax({

            url : 'your_url',
            type: 'GET', 
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            data : ({

             traname: nameval,
             tranamount: amountval

            }),

            success: function (response) {

            },
            error: function ()
            {

            }

        });
  ```

  hope this answer is useful to you

Comment: Thank for the response. I already have those dependencies. I have tried to add the dataType, contentType, and mineType, but it doesnt change the result, and the console, now display "name = null - amount = null"

Comment: have you tried to use 'Get' request and declare data such as in my example. I have never used your declaration of 'data'

Comment: I have added a new method to support for GET and try your code. It give me the same HTTP 405 status. Btw, since it is a form, I am trying to send it using POST.

Comment: i've implemented your situation and it works pretty fine with 'get' request unlike 'post'. also i have omitted jackson-core dependency.and your declaration of data works fine =)